# How does Google Analytics determine if a user is mobile or not?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics-api

i am tracking my website through Google Analytics.but in case of mobile vs website visitors i am not geting proper output.
so i just want to know how google decides, how it filter that is user comming from Mobile or Website/pc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From User agent you can determine that http request is from which device.

[Check this for more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)